# How to improve std::tuple with vacant fields?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I think it could make a sense to have void fields in std::tuple, as long as you don't access this field - but you should be able to instantiate the tuple. Here's an example:

```
template <typename... T>
struct Table {
  std::vector<std::tuple<T...>> data;
  std::tuple<std::unordered_map<T, std::vector<size_t>>...> indices;
};
```

Here we have a field in indices for every data column. Suppose that you don't create indices for every column. Ideally, I'd want to not pay the cost of having an empty std::unordered_map I never use.

What alternatives I have here?

Edit: in other words, how I can create something like *sparse* tuple?

Comment: because you cannot make one with `class`

Comment: you can use your own or std `null-type` instead of void.

Comment: `std::tie` uses `std::ignore` for somewhat similar purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how allowing `void` in `tuple` would help in your example. Are you saying some of the types in `T...` are `void`? Then `std::unordered_map<T,...>` ain't gonna fly either. Could you explain further what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: apple apple - my custom "null" type would still have size > 0.

Comment: Igor - I meant that if I could replace variadic expression in the definition of indices with somthing, which maps only _some_ colums to std::unordered_map<>, and maps it to void for other columns.

Comment: @rincewind every implementations of `std::tuple` I know make use of empty base class optimization, which makes any empty struct take 0 space in memory.

Comment: Guillaume - thanks, empty struct it is then!

Comment: Incidentally, `std::ignore` is very likely implemented as an empty struct.

Comment: Do you know which columns will be used at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: Your title seems not to describe the question well, so I edited the title. If it changes your intent, please feel free to tell me or to roll it back.

Comment: xskxzr - thanks for editing the title. I realized almost immediately after posting that the title was not right, but, somehow, didn't think about editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically because the types for tuple must be referenceable. Semantically, because void is not really a full-status type.

`void` more a like no-type. You can't make a reference to it, `sizeof` is not really legal, and to be used as a type for tuple it would have to be. Which would spin all sorts of strange questions. So what should be sizeof(void)? Are `tuple<int,void>` and `tuple<int>` the same or not?

So the idiomatic solution is to use an actual type designated for the job [`std::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore) which is literally made for this:

> An object of unspecified type such that any value can be assigned to it with no effect. Intended for use with `std::tie` when unpacking a `std::tuple`, as a placeholder for the arguments that are not used.

It's also defined in `tuple`, so don't make your own struct, trust the standard library.

Comment: So looks like std::ignore is a value, not a type. What do I use for the type - decltype(std::ignore), or there's some name for it?